# Overloading operator + for inserting a node in a BinaryTree

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-search-tree

Those are my classes for the Binary Tree :

```
class Node
{
    friend class BinaryTree;
    int value;
    Node *left, *right;
};

class BinaryTree
{
private :
    Node *first ;
public :
    void insert_node(int x);
    void delete_node(int x);
    void in_order_traversal();
    void print_leafs (Node *first);
    void print_leafs2 ();
    int get_height();
    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();

    // operator oveloading
};
```

I want to overload the + operator so I can insert one new element to the tree, the sequence should be like this :

```
int x;
BinaryTree *bt;
x + bt; // or bt + x;
```

I already have a method that insert a node to the tree, and all I have to do is to call that method in the overloading operator + code. This is how I tried to do it :

```
//inline declaration
friend BinaryTree& operator + ( BinaryTree& bt, const int x)
{
    bt.insert_node(x);
    return bt;
}
```

I don't know why but when I debug this code, the line

```
bt + x;
```

is ignored by the compiler.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Be glad that it doesn't work, because it's very misleading notation. Most any programmer expects `+` to produce a result, not to modify things. Voted to close as typo.

Comment: Your code is not quite consistent if you really call x+bt where bt is a pointer, this is of course a pointer shift! Moreover i would use the << operator as it is more commonly used to add things

Comment: I know it is stupid to use the + operator for adding a node to the tree, but this is a project for school and this was the task :(

Comment: I will use the << operator too and tell the professor your point of view, which i find pretty straightforward. Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `x` is declared as an `int` and `bt` is declared as a pointer, using `x + bt;` or `bt + x;` evaluates to a pointer and the value is discarded.

In order to invoke the function `friend BinaryTree& operator + ( BinaryTree& bt, const int x)`, the LHS of the operator must be an object of type `BinaryTree`, not a pointer to a `BinaryTree`.

You need to use:

```
*bt + x;
```

That's just the syntactic part. Semantically speaking, that operator overload function does not seem right.

When you use

```
int a  = 10;
a + 20;
```

the value of `a` is not changed. The last line simply evaluates to `30` and the value is discarded.

If you use

```
int b = a + 20;
```

`b` gets assigned the value of `30` but `a` remains unchanged. You may want to create similar semantics for your operator overload function.

```
BinaryTree bt1;             // Create an empty tree.
BinaryTree bt2  = bt1 + 1;  // bt2 contains everything in bt1 + 1.
```

In that case, change the function to:

```
friend BinaryTree operator + ( BinaryTree const& bt, int x)
//               |                       |           ^^^ No need for const
//               |                       ^^^^^^^^ Change it to const&
//              ^^^ Change the return type to be an object, not a reference.    
{
   BinaryTree ret(bt);  // Provide a proper copy constructor
   ret.insert_node(x);
   return ret;
}
```

Comment: @CalinCretu, glad I was able to help.